# Nonhomogeneous Equations: the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this non-homogeneous Equation:

$$y'' + y'  = t + \sin(t) $$

Is the particular solution $At(\cos t) + Bt(\sin t) + Ct$?

Could somebody tell me if my guess is right or not?

Because another person told me it is $At^2 + Bt + C\sin t + D\cos t$

Comment: Try each of them in the DE and check which one is correct. By the way, **Welcome** to the site !

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the difference between
$$
y''+y=t+\sin t
$$
and
$$
y''+y'=t+\sin t.
$$
Your first ansatz is correct for the first equation, while the second is valid for the second equation.

As always, you need to determine the characteristic polynomial and its roots. For the second equation, that of your task, you get
$$
\lambda^2+\lambda=0\implies \lambda=0\lor \lambda=-1.
$$
The right side has characteristic exponents $λ=0$ twice for the $te^{0t}$ term and $λ=\pm i$ for $\sin t=\frac1{2i}(e^{it}-e^{-it})$. As the first term is in resonance with the left side, you need to add the multiplicity of the left side to its degree, giving $$t^1(A+Bt)e^{0t}$$ as trial solution. The other term, as it is not in resonance, gets the standard $$C\sin t+D\cos t.$$

Answer (score 0):

Calling $Y = y'$ we have

$$
Y'+Y = t + \sin t
$$

This is a non-homogeneous linear DE so we can write it's solution as

$$
Y = Y_h + Y_p\\
Y_h'+Y_h = 0\\
Y_p'+Y_p = t + \sin t
$$
The homogeneous has the solution $Y_h = C e^{-t}$ The particular can be solved using the variation of parameters (Lagrange) by assuming that $Y_p = C(t)e^{-t}$.

After substitution into the particular we obtain

$$
e^{-t}C'(t) = t + \sin t
$$

and after integration

$$
C(t) = e^t(t-1+\frac 12(\sin t-\cos t))
$$

then

$$
Y_p =  e^t(t-1+\frac 12(\sin t-\cos t))e^{-t} = t-1+\frac 12(\sin t-\cos t)
$$

so

$$
Y = C_0 e^{-t} + t-1+\frac 12(\sin t-\cos t)
$$

but $Y = y'$ so finally

$$
y = \int \left(C_0 e^{-t} + t-1+\frac 12(\sin t-\cos t)\right)dt
$$